# Are application layer protocols part of library routines?

Tags: networking, libraries, architecture, protocols

Where do application layer protocols reside? Are they part of library routines of language e.g. C, C++, Java?

As [goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25985/goldilocks) says in his answer, this is about the implementation of application layer protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where do application layer protocols reside?

Protocols are an abstraction, so they don't really "reside" anywhere beyond specifications and other documentation.

If you mean, where are they *implemented,* there's a few common patterns:

- They may be implemented first in native C as libraries which can be wrapped by for use in other languages (since most other languages are themselves implemented in C and have a C interface). E.g., encryption protocols are generally like this.
- They may be implemented from scratch as libraries or modules for use in a specific language, using just that language (and/or the language it is implemented in).  E.g., high level networking protocols.
- They may be implemented from scratch by a given application.

These are all pure userland implementations, but some protocols -- e.g., low level networking -- may be implemented in the kernel.  This may include a corresponding native C userland library (as with networking and filesystems) or the kernel (including independent kernel modules) may provide a language agnostic interface via procfs, `/dev`, etc.

Comment: Unlike the 2nd and 3rd patterns, I cannot understand the 1st pattern, probably it is related to programming. Are there any specific books about application layer protocols implementation?

Comment: I've never seen one, but there may be.  You could think of a protocol implementation the same way as a language implementation -- e.g., the GNU C library usually used on linux is an *implementation* of the Standard C Specification (or more specifically, several variants of it which can be indicated with a compiler option), and POSIX.  For example, standard C does not include networking, but pretty much all libraries include it in some (platform specific) way.  Networking is made possible by *[various protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers)* that a system...

Comment: ...must implement in order to network with other computers.  So there is a POSIX specification for how this is handled in userspace, and on POSIX systems this is implemented in the C library.  The POSIX spec WRT networking is about the C interface to, e.g., TCP/IP.  But TCP/IP is actually implemented in the kernel, and the C userland library provides a bridge to that which satisfies the POSIX spec for a TCP/IP interface.  In turn, languages like perl, python, ruby, etc. -- which are implemented in C -- "wrap" those C functions and provide a modular interface...

Comment: ...so you can write TCP/IP networking code in python, perl, ruby, etc.  Have a **[look here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm)** and search for `socket`.  You'll get a list of C functions that a POSIX compliant system must provide for writing networking code.  The GNU C library implements that.  Higher level languages built on C tend to reflect those in various ways, but they also try to do so so that an implementation of python on e.g. windows (which is not POSIX) works exactly the same way WRT networking (i.e., they provide a *cross-platform* interface in that regard).